# Install jitsi with oracle jdk

Tags: linux, oracle, java, jitsi

recently I UNinstalled OpenJDK and installed Oracle JDK 1.6 on my Linux Mint 16 Device, using this description:_

http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1372

But today I've recognized that my messenger jitsi disappeared. It seems it's depending on the OpenJDK but I don't believe that it is imposible to run it with the original Oracle JDK which is the one and only JDK for me.

Trying to install jitsi with

```
dpkg -i jitsi_2.5.5065-1_amd64.deb
```

results into this error:

```
(Reading database ... 171948 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace jitsi 2.5.5065-1 (using jitsi_2.5.5065-1_amd64.deb) ...
 Unpacking replacement jitsi ...
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of jitsi:
  jitsi depends on default-jre | java6-runtime; however:
   Package default-jre is not installed.
   Package java6-runtime is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing jitsi (--install):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 Processing triggers for man-db ...
 Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
 Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
 Processing triggers for mime-support ...
 Processing triggers for menu ...
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  jitsi
```

If i try to install it with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then my system wants to reinstall OpenJDK-7. But I don't want to have this sh** OpenJDK on my device.

I tried to tell the system now to use only Oracle JDK 1.6, regarding the hints on this page:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre

But it didn't help me. So how can I use jitsi withouth reinstalling OpenJDK?

Thanks+Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jitsi Generic Installer, which just needs Java, and doesn't check for any dependencies.

Here is the link: https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/generic/